# Can we have sex with a girl in our thoughts

Tags: knowing-islam

क्या हम अपने ख्यालों में किसी लड़की के साथ सेक्स कर सकते है?

Can we have sex with a girl in our thoughts?

Please tell me anyone

Answer (score 1):

Jesus said to his followers:

> "Moses ibn Imran commanded you not to commit adultery; But I advise
> you not to think of adultery; For he who thinks of adultery is like
> one who lights a fire in a beautifully painted room. In this case,
> although the house may not burn in the fire; "But at least the smoke
> makes it black."

According to the Shari'a, the thought of sin in sexual matters, especially if it is involuntary, is not a sin. But the human must avoid the premise that causes these thoughts ...

According to Imam Ali (a.s.):

> "The one who thinks much about sins, his sins draw him to himself."

Reference: https://article.tebyan.net/243501/

Answer (score 0):

Logically speaking one cannot 'have sex with a girl' in our thoughts, since this is a physical act; presumably you mean merely to 'imagine'.

I don't know of a Hadith specifically on this, but given that one is expected to form relationships, to marry, to have children; I don't see it being particularly unislamic to do so.

Unless, one is addicted to it; there is such a thing as sex addiction after all; and one that appears to be promoted by a sex-addicted entertainment industry ... that I would say is haram, as it causes harm.